# variable in range function

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I am trying to write a script that creates new file names (the content of the files is the same). The result should be as follows:

`file_10_11.txt`, `file_10_12.txt`, ..., `file_10_100.txt`

(resulting are 90 files and this is the first batch of files). Then

`file_10_11.txt`, `file_10_12.txt`, ..., `file_10_99.txt`

(resulting are 89 files and this is the second batch of files). Then

`file_10_11.txt`, `file_10_12.txt`, ..., `file_10_98.txt`.

And at last all the way until file_10_**10**.txt.
As you see the last number drops from 100 to 10 with a step of 1.

What I am doing now for the first batch of files is the following:

```
for x in range(9,100):
    initial_file = 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test\X_Y.txt'
    dest_file = 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test\file_' + str(x+1) + '_100.idf'
    shutil.copy2(initial_file, dest_file)
```

How can I put in a loop the rest batches of file renaming?

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the language or shell being used.

Comment: Is this Python code? Maybe you should add a tag with the name of the language and also tell it in your question.

Comment: I don't understand what any of this means. What is your expected output? You name 3 lists of files as your expected result but surely you just want the one loop and not to repeatedly overwrite the same files? Are you ultimately just asking how to make a loop that counts backwards from 100 to 10?? Then your range should be `range(100, 9, -1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need this because you are generating the same file name multiple times. For instance, `file_10_10.txt` will be generated 91 times. But what you want can be accomplish with two backwards loops:

```
for x in range(100, 9, -1):
    for y in range(x, 9, -1):
        print 'file_10_' + str(y) + '.txt'
```